# How do you mock an internal function being used within react component with jest and react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm introducing react testing into my teams codebase, however I can't seem to mock functions the way I do in regular util/helper functions elsewhere in the codebase.

My component looks like:

```
import {
  util1,
  util2,
} from '../utils/utils_for_this_component';

const ParentComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
  const result = util1(prop1, prop2);
  return (
    <ChildComponent1
      aProp={util2(result)}
    >
    ...
    </ChildComponent1>
  );
};
```

So I just want to validate that when I render this prop, the `result` being passed to util2 is what we expect it to be.

```
import * as Utils from '../utils/utils_for_this_component';
...
it('should do the thing', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Utils, 'util2');
    render(<Provider store={store}>{<ParentComponent {...props} />}</Provider>);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

But I'm never getting this to pass, it says my spy was never called.
Am I missing something here? Why cant I spy into the actual util2 being used?

Eventually I want to verify the param being passed to util2 is correct, but now Id just like to validate its being spied on correctly. I know the function is being called because 1. it works in prod, and 2. If i log the result, it shows up when I run the test case.

The error:

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    
    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

      55 |     const spy = jest.spyOn(Utils, 'util2');
      56 |     render(<Provider store={store}>{<ParentComponent ... />}</Provider>);
    > 57 |     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      58 |   });
      59 | });
      60 |
```

Comment: If im not mistaken but react-testing-library focuses on what the user sees on the screen, not internal functions. So the goal when using react testing library is to test components that the users can see. Hopefully someone can chime in, and give you a better answer.

Comment: Not necessarily, the react testing library is meant to provide you react functionality to test with, ie: render, componentDidMount, etc. For example, it's what provides the `render` function through which Im testing this component, which then allows me to mock the child components and validate props are being passed around correctly and things like that.

Comment: I would expect a spy to work due to how ES modules work. But a safer way is `jest.mock('...utils', () => { let Utils = jest.requireActual('...utils'); jest.spyOn(Utils, 'util2'); return Utils; })`. It should take place at top level, not inside `it`.